# Flutter How do I iterate over each item in a ListView?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, listview, dart

I'm new to flutter and have created a simple app to display some custom List Tiles. In each tile, it's possible to increase or decrease the count by the + and - buttons.

But I want to get these data into a map, on the click of the button "Order". For example, my map would be like `{'shoes': 1, 'books': 2, 'water': 3}` etc.

I've tried Provider, StreamBuilder, BLoC etc. But since I'm a beginner, I couldn't get a real use of any of those.

Could any of you please tell me how to get this data into a map.

Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: could you show code which used to render above list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `Map` like this:

```
List<String> products = ['shoes', 'books', 'water'];
Map<String,int> map = Map.fromIterables(products , 0);
```

When user press - or + buttons in each tile, update your equvalent <key, value> in your map.
For example in `onTap` event of `shoes`'s + button you have

```
map.update('shoes', (v)=> v+1);
```

Then you can use updated `map` in `onTap` of `Order` button.

For more info about Map in dart visit [this](https://bezkoder.com/dart-map/) link.

Comment: thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks again, for giving the answer in a concise format so that even a beginner can understand.

Comment: " The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<int>' "

Comment: @MwBakker where do you get this error?. It's been a while so the codes could have changed :)

Comment: On doing the exact same thing, maybe it's no longer possible at flutter >= 2.3

Answer (score 0):

With "bloc", you need to build your events, states in the Bloc would be something like that:

The event will be where the Bloc is triggered.

```
part of 'something_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class SomethingEvent{}

class ListOfSomething extends SomethingEvent{}

class SomethingElse extends SomethingEvent{
  final String input;
  SomethingElse({this.input});

  List<Object> get props => [input];
}
```

The state is where the result of what was triggered in the event will be manifested, whether successful or unsuccessful:

```
part of 'Something_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class SomethingState{}

class SomethingInitial extends SomethingState{}

class SomethingLoading extends SomethingState{}

class SomethingSuccess extends SomethingState{
  final String success;
  SomethingSuccess({this.success});
}
```

The "bloc" is where to manage these events and states:

```
part 'something_event.dart';
part 'something_state.dart';

class SomethingBloc extends Bloc<SomethingEvent,SomethingState>{
 final ServiceFacade service;
  SomethingBloc({this.service});

  @override
  SomethingState get initialState => SomethingInitial();

  @override
  Stream<SomethingState> mapEventToState(SomethingEvent event) async* {
    if(event is SomethingEvent){
      final failureOrSuccess = await service.call(event.cardId);
      yield failureOrSuccess.fold(
              (failure) => (failure is GeneralFailure)
                  ? SomethingErrorState(error: failure.message)
                  : null,
              (list) => SomethingState(success: list)
      );
    }
   
  }

}
```

The screen will look something like this, you can trigger the event in an `OnPressed`, or initialize it in the `initState()`:

```
    BlocConsumer<SomethingBloc, SomethingState>(
                    listener: (context, state) {
                      if (state is SomethingLoadingState) {
                       
                      } else if (state is SomethingErrorState) {
                        
                      } else if (state is SomethingSuccess) {
                        
                      }
                    },
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is SomethingSuccess) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: paddingHorizontal,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                for (var item in state.list)
                                 Container(

                                 child: Text('${item}')
                                   )
                       ]
                            ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

I hope I've helped in general terms.

Comment: I will look into BLoCs, but I could get it done using @R.Shpd's answer. Thanks for your answer.